# Start activity adding another activity on the stack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Here is my activities scenario:

A1 -> A2 -> (A3) -> A4

I am currently in A2, and I would like to go from A2 directly to A4, but if the user presses the back button in A4, go to A3. If the user presses the back button in A3, go to A2, and if the user presses the back button in A2, go to A1. Which one is the best way to achieve that?

I've tried three different options so far:

1. Using TaskStackBuilder: Couldn't achieve exactly what I wanted, cause I was to creating a fresh stack of activities, so A1 and A2 where recreated (I would rather them not to be recreated).
2. Calling startActivity(A3) and startActivity(A4) consecutively from A2.
3. Call startActivity(A3) from A2, setting an Intent Extra. In the onCreate() method of A3, check the value of the Intent Extra, and depending on its value, launch automatically A4.

Which one do you think is the best approach to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good user experience. Why would the user expect to see A3 if he presses the BACK button in A4?

However, if this is what you want to do, I would definitely opt for choice #3. A2 should start A3 and pass an extra that tells A3 to immediately start A4. This choice is the most straightforward from a coding perspective and it will be easy for someone else to follow if they have to maintain it.

Comment: The main reason I want to do it is because A2 is a kind of notification centre. I would like to redirect the user to the selected  content by creating the adequate route/stack of activities.

Comment: In choice #3, I would have to modify the onCreate() method for each Activity I would like to redirect to another one. I would not need to do that in choice #2. Taking that into account, do you still think #3 is the best choice?

Comment: Yes, I still think #3 is the best choice. Redirecting to another activity is like 2 lines of code. And at least this makes it clear what you are doing when you go back to look at it 6 months later. I recommend this type of "dispatcher" activity all the time to solve situations where you need to change the normal flow of the navigation in a way that isn't directly supported by Andoid.

Answer (score 0):

Create A4 from A2;

Intercept back pressed event on A4;

override it and create A3 finishing A4.

i find it a good solution, because with A3 you are not going really back. The system will be happy :)

**on A4**

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A3.class);    
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: If A3 invoked A4, your code will create a new A3, which isn't the real deal in most situations

Comment: you're right :) my solution is for a static route. so #2 is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As Steve said, I also would like to be able to access to A4 trough A3